# If B contains an open set or a set of strictly positive Lebesgue measure, then the Hausdorff dimension of $B$ is $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

For every $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ one has $\dim_H B \le n$, where $\dim_H$ is the Hausdorff dimension. If B contains an open set or a set of strictly positive Lebesgue measure, then $\dim_H B=n$.

I am looking at the following solution to this problem from Rene Schilling.

Solution. We know that $0 \le \dim_H B \le n$. If $B$ contains an open set $U$ (or a set of non-zero Lebesgue measure), we see $H^n(B) \ge H^n(U) > 0$; intersect with a large open ball $K$ to make sure that $H^n(B \cap K) < \infty$ and $U \cap K \subset B \cap K$. THis shows $n = \dim_H(B\cap K)\le \dim_H (B) \le n$.

However, I don't see why we need  to consider a large open ball $K$ in this case. We already have $0<H^n(B)<\infty$, so by the definition of the Hausdorff dimension, i.e. 
$$\dim_H(B) = \sup\{s \in (0,\infty): H^s(B)>0\}$$ don't we immediately have that the dimension is $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But it is not given that $H^{n}(B)<\infty$, it could be $H^{n}(B)=\infty$, so we need to intersect with a larger ball $K$ to make sure that $H^{n}(B\cap K)<\infty$, and we also have $H^{n}(B\cap K)>0$, then $\dim_{H}H^{n}(B\cap K)=n$.

Comment: Right I thought $H^n(B) \le n$. But then how do we ensure a large ball $K$ to have $0<H^n(B\cap K) < \infty$? I think we can have $H^n(B \cap K) \le H^n(K)$, and use that the Hausdorff measure of a ball is finite, to get $<\infty$ part, but I'm not sure how to get $0<H^n(B \cap K)$.

Comment: Because you already had $$H^{n}(U)>0, and $U$ is a ball, as long as $K$ is another ball such that $U\subseteq K$, then $U\subseteq B\cap K$, so $H^{n}(B\cap K)\geq H^{n}(U)>0$. But $H^{n}(B\cap K)\leq H^{n}(K)<\infty$.

Comment: In the case of $U$ simply being a set of positive Lebesgue measure, we can take a sequence of open balls increasing to $R^n$, and take some $K$ that has $H^n(U \cap K)>0$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the sequence of increasing balls, and pick one of them large enough to complete the job.